# How to use the output of the DFT to compute the period of a function?

Tags: period-finding-algorithm

Have been trying to understand how I use the output of DFT to compute the period of a periodic function. Specifically, this is my code:

```python
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def modexp(a, p, N):
    return a**p % N

arr = np.arange(0, 25)
L2 = modexp(2, arr, 15)
L = L2 - np.mean(L)
fft = np.fft.fft(L)
plt.grid(True)
plt.plot(L)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(abs(fft))
```

This is the function output : `[1 2 4 8 1 2 4 8 1 2 4 8 1 2 4 8 1 2 4 8 1 2 4 8 1]` and we can see that the period is 4.

How do I deduce this from the fft output?

Will really appreciate logical, step-by-step guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The FFT output of your code looks similar to the above.  Along the x-axis is the frequency.  N = 25 in your example, and you see a peak at x = 6, so you read this as a frequency of 6/(25-1) = 1/4.  Period is the inverse of frequency = 4.